# CSS Family Issue

Tags: css

I am using this css script :

```
#top_menu li a {
 display:block;
 margin-top:2px;
 font-family: 'Federant', cursive;
 font-size:16px;
 color:#8f7a60;
 padding:21px 30px;
 border-right:1px solid #1e1a18;
 border-left:1px solid #302a26;
}
```

for a text on my website but it doesn't not make it federant family. How to include it ?

Comment: Use @font-face property of css , please refer to this link http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/embed-custom-fonts-on-your-website-with-the-font-face-property/

Comment: If an answer is correct, please remember to mark it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without any details on the context of the provided CSS, we can only guess the possible issues.

The most likely is that the Federant font is not a standard web font. If it is not installed on the visitor's system, the page cannot use it.

- You can provide fallback standard fonts (you should in fact).
- You can also, if the licence of the font allows it, embed it in your stylesheet. So the browser will load the font and apply it to the links.

Here's an example of code to embed a font :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Federant';
    src: url('fonts/Federant.eot'),
         url('fonts/Federant.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('fonts/Federant.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: There are no “standard web fonts”. There is literally no font that is installed on all devices used to access the internet. The relevant thing is that there is no font under the given name in the system(s) used for testing.

Comment: Indeed, I should have chosen another word. W3C was more cautious with the wording Web Safe Fonts : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Comment: w3schools is bogus and has nothing to do with W3C, though they intentionally mislead people by using a domain name that suggests affiliation with W3C, and their page on “web safe fonts” is all bogus; not all the declarations there are bad, but there is nothing “web safe” about them.

Comment: Yeah, ok, safe does not mean bullet proof. If you use Arial or verdana, you can be quite comfortable that most system will be able to render it. If you set-up a fallback of 2-3 wildly used fonts, you can consider yourself safe.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the CSS does not know what that font is, so it must be included.

See, there are webfonts which are built-in fonts in the browser, such has sans-serif, arial, serif, etc. If it is not a 'webfont' then it must be manually included.

To do so, you will need the font files, and then you can include them in your CSS like this:

```
@font-face Federant  {
    font-family: 'Federant';
    src: url(../fonts/Federant.woff);
}

#top_menu li a {
  font-family: Federant;
}
```